# Power BI Values not being correctly passed to Paginated Report

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded

I have created a paginated report via Power BI Report Builder; I have also created a Power BI Dashboard to render and filter the report.  I have linked up all of the report parameters to slicers so that the users can filter the pages that are returned to them.

For troubleshooting, I am rendering the incoming parameters to the report.

```
="WellId: " & Parameters!pLocationId.Value & " ---- Reporting Name: " & Parameters!pProject.Value & " ---- Year: " & Parameters!pYear.Value & " ---- Quarter:" & Parameters!pQuarter.Value
```

It appears as through unselected slicer values are being pushed to the report.
[image]

Has anyone else run into this or have a recommendation for how to only receive slicer values that are selected?  As near as I can tell the first value is passed when nothing is selected from the slicer.

Comment: What does this return? `=Join(Parameters!pLocationId.Value,", ")`. Is your parameter in the paginated report multi-select? https://www.timmitchell.net/post/2019/12/22/the-join-function-in-reporting-services/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @GregGalloway to get me thinking about concatenation.

I opted to combine the filtered values with a delimeter (tilde).

DAX:

```
pWellId = IF(
    ISFILTERED(ReportFilters[locationid]), 
    CONCATENATEX ( VALUES (ReportFilters[locationid] ) , [locationid] , "~"),
    BLANK()
)
```

On the report side, I set a single text parameter and passed in the above value.

This is then passed to the DB (Sql Server) where the values are then split out:

```
wellId IN (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@sqlWellId, '~') WHERE value <> '')
```